# Access Denied error when i download file using sas and curl

Tags: curl, sas

I am using the below sas and curl code to download a file from web.

```
data _null_;
    x "cd c:\sasdata";
    x "curl -O http://nseindia.com/content/indices/histdata/CNX%20NIFTY21-03-2014-21-03-
2014.csv";
run;
```

the file download but contents are below mentioned

`<HTML><HEAD>`
`<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>`
`</HEAD><BODY>`
`<H1>Access Denied</H1>`

`You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;nseindia&#46;com&#47;content&#47;indices&#47;histdata&#47;CNX&#37;20NIFTY21&#45;03&#45;2014&#45;21&#45;03&#45;2014&#46;csv" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;e5bef75&#46;1395641322&#46;926b13`
`</BODY>`
`</HTML>`

two days back every thing is working fine but suddenly above error occurred.

please help to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding user agent `-A "Mozilla"` works for me:

```
curl -A "Mozilla" http://nseindia.com/content/indices/histdata/CNX%20NIFTY21-03-2014-21-03-2014.csv
```

It returns:

```
"Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Shares Traded","Turnover (Rs. Cr)"
"21-Mar-2014","     6515.20","     6522.90","     6485.70","     6493.20","      189854420","         8841.94"
```